# VB.net Dropdown list

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dropdown

I have a list with 2 columns, ID and Display Name.

| ID | Display Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Customer A |
| 2 | Customer B |
| 3 | Customer C |

When the user select Customer B, I want the text to display 2, not customer B.  I thought I've done this before but can't seem to get it working.

```vb
Protected Sub ddlDelegatedTo_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlDelegatedTo.SelectedIndexChanged 
    Me.ddlDelegatedTo.Text = Me.ddlDelegatedTo.SelectedItem.Text 
    ' Me.ddlDelegatedTo.SelectedValue 
End Sub
```

Comment: Post sample code what you have done so far

Comment: Protected Sub ddlDelegatedTo_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlDelegatedTo.SelectedIndexChanged
        Me.ddlDelegatedTo.Text = Me.ddlDelegatedTo.SelectedItem.Text
        Me.ddlDelegatedTo.SelectedValue

    End Sub

Comment: I think the place to start here for you will be understanding the html rendered to the browser, and how the specific html elements work. This has the look of something that really should be done entirely in the browser via javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you are describing I think this is what you are trying to achieve

```
Private Sub ddlDelegate_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlDelegate.SelectedIndexChanged
        ddlDelegate.Items().FindByValue(ddlDelegate.SelectedValue).Text = ddlDelegate.SelectedValue
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dim Number as integer = (dropdownlist.indexof(dropdownlist1.selecteditem) + 1)
```